# using ajax jquery to run php script

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter, I am trying to get a php script to run after a user clicks on a submit button.  I have followed quite a few tutorials and have come up with the following code:

If it would help to see the actual page you can visit it here: http://rickymason.net/townbuilder
guest/guest to login (currently required)

In my view (structures.php), I have :

```
<div id="structures">
<h1>Build</h1>
<form name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST">
    <select name="buildID" class="buildClass">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Build a Structure</option>
<?php foreach ($structures as $structure_info): ?>
<option name='<?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?>' value='<?php echo $structure_info['str_id'] ?>' data-icon='<?php echo $structure_info['str_imageloc'] ?>' data-html-text='<?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?><i>
    <?php echo $structure_info['timebuildmins'] ?> minutes<br><?php echo $structure_info['buy_gold'] ?> gold</i>'><?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <div id="buildSubmit">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="output"> Result here</div>
```

This creates my select form and creates it in html.  I then created a .js file to run the ajax:

```
$("#submit").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '../php/build.php',        
data: "",
dataType: 'json',                     
success: function(data)          
{
  alert("success!");
} 
});
});
```

I tried to keep it as simple as I could, just for testing purposes.  Javascript is new to me, and I find it extremely confusing for some reason.  From what I can gather, this script should activate after the submit button is pressed.  It then runs the build.php script, then if it returns an echo through json, it alerts success. right?

my build.php script is below:

```
<?php
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_structure (str_id, user_id) VALUES ('7', '7')";
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');      
    echo "success";
?>
```

Again, very simple...

Unfortunately, when I click submit, the page seems to "refresh" but nothing happens.  I don't expect anything to happen on the page, but the database doesn't receive any values either.

I do not have the build.php or build.js files in a controller or model, they are outside the application directory and are accessed outside the CI uri/url structure.

As of right now, I am simply trying to successfully run a php script by clicking submit.  My final goal is to take the str_id value that is created for the form, then pass that variable and the user_id into the build.php file, create the db entry, then refresh the page to display the updated DB info.

Obviously, it is not working! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `echo "success";` doesn't return a JSON string. Also you don't prevent the form from being submitted. Also do you really need all those opening / closing php tags to build your select box?

Comment: First of all, you don't have anything with ID = "submit", what's jQuery supposed to pick?

Comment: thanks, I removed id='submit' before posting the code.  I did so because a specific example I was mimicking did not have it, as I believe they were calling the form name.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script works with an element having id "submit"  (because you use `"#submit"` as the selector)

Use the click event instead of submit

Either you can give an id to your submit like this

and use like this

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
   // your rest of code
});
```

or use the class name

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
   // your rest of code
});
```

But It is always better to use the id becaues there will be only one ( and should be) element with an id.  More than one element can have the same class.

Comment: The submit() event would be just fine, if he had a submit input with the right id, of course

Comment: I added id='btnSubmit' to the submit tag.  Then I changed the js to $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){.  I am still not getting a change to the database.  Could it be due to the fact that, since the build.php file is being called, and is not being loaded through the controller, it needs to get connected once again to the DB?  I will try that and report back.

Comment: check in firbug to see whether a call is being made to the correct file ( i mean the path)

Comment: Thank you all.  I was able to get it working based on all the advice given.  After the small changes made, I decided to the code to my controller.  It currently is working! So at least now I have something to build on.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `action` attribute for your `form`:

```
<form action="build.php" name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST">`
```

OR:

```
<form action="<?php /* Script code here */ ?>" name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery code targets an element with the id of 'submit' however, your form has an id of 'buildForm' hence the code does not target the form and when you click submit it just goes on with its normal behaviour, which causes the screen to refresh, To fix this, change the selector in your jquery code

```
$("#buildForm").submit(function(e){
    // the rest of the code here remains
});
```

This should fix it